# 'Cannot retrieve class for valid (unclassed) type 'void'' in Pygobject?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I've installed Pygobject on windows, and when I tried to run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

class StackWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Stack Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        stack = Gtk.Stack()
        stack.set_transition_type(Gtk.StackTransitionType.SLIDE_LEFT_RIGHT)
        stack.set_transition_duration(1000)

        checkbutton = Gtk.CheckButton("Click me!")
        stack.add_titled(checkbutton, "check", "Check Button")

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<big>A fancy label</big>")
        stack.add_titled(label, "label", "A label")

        stack_switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher()
        stack_switcher.set_stack(stack)
        vbox.pack_start(stack_switcher, True, True, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(stack, True, True, 0)

win = StackWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I got error an message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "F:\ASM_Archive\gui01.py", line 13
    stack = Gtk.Stack()
Warning: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type 'void'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\ASM_Archive\gui01.py", line 29, in <module>
    win = StackWindow()
  File "F:\ASM_Archive\gui01.py", line 13, in __init__
    stack = Gtk.Stack()
TypeError: could not get a reference to type class
```

Does it mean that I have installed something wrong or missed something?
I can create windows, add buttons etc. but when I try to add something more like 'Gtk.Stack()' or 'Gtk.ListBox()' I got errors.

Comment: I would guess that you've downloaded an earlier version of GTK than 3.10, which was the first version that Stack and ListBox showed up in.

Comment: I think ptomato is right. It seems that you installed it in Windows, check the version installed first.

Comment: @ptomato: If that were the case, I think the error would be more along the lines of "AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'Stack'"

Comment: True, but it is suspicious that other classes work and only the >3.10 classes don't. Maybe they are somehow picking up a GTK shared library with a different version than the typelib.